# Laravel app not accessible on Apache webserver

Tags: laravel, apache, deployment

I have uploaded a Laravel 7.26.0 app to my VPS (Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache webserver).

I cannot reach the index.php from a browser.

The browser just stays blank. No error messages.

##### Troubleshooting tests performed

###### Test-1: Accessing another file then index.php on the failing app, physically located on its /public folder

Result:

I can access it through `ip-address:virtual port/test.txt`.
This should mean that Apache is up and running and able to route user through virtual port to the app folder `public`.

###### Test-2 - Creating a parallell public folder, called `public2`

Adding an index.php with only a short text string.

Result:

Works, to access the newly created `index.php`, note that the original setup with specific laravel content of `index.php`, is not there anymore. The value of this test is pretty low since it only proves Apache is correctly routing virtual hosts to the correct folder, not that Laravel can redirect all incoming call from index.php to proper routes.

###### Test-3: Creating Laravel app directly on server

Result:

It works creating an app directly on the server and accessing its index.php page.

##### My settings

###### Enabled rewrite module

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

###### Adjusted permissions on Laravel app

```
sudo chown -R trader:www-data 1_sandbox
find 1_sandbox -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find 1_sandbox -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

sudo chgrp -R www-data 1_sandbox/storage 1_sandbox/bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx 1_sandbox/storage 1_sandbox/bootstrap/cache
```

###### Added setting for virtual hosts

File: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/1_sandbox/public
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

    
<Directory /var/www/laravel/1_sandbox/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
#       RewriteEngine On
</Directory>
```

###### Added ports in Ports.conf

File: `/etc/apache2/ports.cont`

```
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

###### `.htaccess` in laravel apps public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Just checking off some boxes:
1: is php enabled correctly? (put phpinfo(); in a index.php)
2: are all laravel required php modules installed?
3: if you set the entire laravel app folder to 777 does it help? (checking to make sure theres no permissions conflicts with apache)
4: is there anything in the error logs?
5: is there anything in the access logs?

Comment: @hurnhu It just started to work now. Seems I had some problems with lack of app key in [.env]. I had to do a "composer install" and "composer dump-autoload" then I could use the command "php artisan key:generate".